# Red frameworks in xcode from CocoaPods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

My frameworks in xcode are all red. I tried re-installing/updating the frameworks by using `pods install` and `pods update`. I also tried changing the path/location of the frameworks as well as re-installing xcode and even updating xcode to the newest beta version.

Comment: What happens after building the project?

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated cocoa pods to 1.4.0 (`sudo gem install cocoapods`?